# How do I use a liquid tag inside a conditional statement

Tags: liquid

I've tried:

{% assign color = {{module_url param='color' -%}} -%}

{% if color == 'red' -%}

Red is the color

{% endif -%}

and lots of variations but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **capture** the `color` variable first, instead of using assign, and then check against that:

```
{% capture color -%}
    {{ module_url param='color' }}
{% endcapture -%}

{% if color == 'red' -%}

Red is the color

{% endif -%}
```